# Mathematically create a positive or negative one using a random number function

Tags: random

If I am in a coding language where I can create a random number for a given range (i.e. 0 to 50, or -30 to 751, etc.) How can I mathematically create a +1 or -1 (not a +1, 0, or -1) using only math and the random function.. no if statements.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Easy. `random(0,1) * 2 - 1` will do it.

Comment: In R:
`system.time(replicate(10,floor(runif(1e6, 0, 2)) * 2 - 1))`
`user  system elapsed` 
`1.07    0.05    1.13`
`system.time(replicate(10,sample(c(1,-1), 1e6, replace = T)))`
`0.39    0.09    0.49`

Comment: Now that I have a little more coding experience under my belt I wonder if ternary `ran(0,1)?-1:1` would be computationally faster

Comment: Possibly. But the ternary conditional operator might be considered a kind of if statement, or at least not "math".

Comment: If you are using c# use random.Next(0, 2) * 2 - 1

Answer (score 4):

You could just get a random number and divide by the absolute value of itself. Something like the following in C#:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
int iNum; 
int result;

iNum = r.Next(-30, 50); //put whatever range you want in here from negative to positive 
result = iNum / (int)Math.Abs(iNum);
```

Comment: Although you might hit a divide by zero. This can be edited to may add to successive rand numbers, i.e. iNum = r.Next(-30,50) + r.Next(-30,50) (or even just add a 1 to the original iNum?). Hopefully whatever language you're using has a good enough random generator where it won't produce the same number (e.g. 0) twice in a row.

Comment: I'm working in objective-c .. this was my original route but I did hit a divide by zero and the application quit hahaha... The user above who commented with `random(0,1) * 2 - 1` has a great method though. :)

Comment: A random number generator that never gives the same number twice in a row wouldn't be particularly "good".

Comment: nithins: Note that if you add two random numbers you don't get a uniform distribution anymore. Could be that it's a non-issue for only two values, but in general I'd be wary of it.